# How do I AUTOMATICALLY decline conflicting meeting requests in outlook 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, calendar

I have set specific meetings in my agenda to block time. You know, so one can actually get some work done.
But people just send meeting requests that conflict with my blocking not available meetings I've defined in my calendar.

My question: 
How do I AUTOMATICALLY decline conflicting meeting requests in outlook 365 ?

P.s. I'm using the Mac version 16.28 <19081202>) and the web client which connect to my company's Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook for mac doesn’t have such an option to realize this. Outlook provides a feature “Schedule Assistance” to help organizer to choose a suitable time for meeting: [Look up someone's schedule in Outlook for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/look-up-someone-s-schedule-in-outlook-for-mac-468e6b1a-c5c2-4378-adc0-dd1e210669c4)

Organizer should look at the schedule and choose a good time.

If you really care about this, you can also change your mailbox type to resource mailbox and use Set-CalendarProcessing cmdlet to set “avoid conflicting meeting requests”.